# what is the best height i should set to, to fit on first look

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website, but i'm trying to show every elements in the div upon first look. Meaning no scrolling is available for the user.

As i know each different computer has different screen resolutions, so what should i do to provide a solution to my problem?

Is there a minimum height that a computer must at least have? So i can set a max-height to my website.. Appreciate any answers. Thanks!

Comment: what about `height: 100%;`? that is 100% of the users screens height. but honestly, this a really bad question that would be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: i know div can be 100%, but i need to know how long should i limit my elements, as i don't want my elements to go beyond a certain limit that enables the scrolling to take place.

Comment: You can't set any webpage on fix height because its depend on your webpage height and screen resolutions which can be different

Comment: It's not a question of screen resolution, but the browser's size. You can resize the browser viewport to as small as you want, starting from 0 pixels.

Comment: ok one important thing, if on different browser viewport, the 100% will scale all my elements in the div proportionally? Or do i have to do something else to my elements to make them scale

Comment: how about you try something before asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set min-height and max-height 100% to page container div.

```
    .container{min-height::100%; max-height:100%; min-width:100%; max-width:100%; float:left;}
```

[Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/gLthLrj4/)

Note:this simple solutions are available in google.

Comment: ok sorry about it.. i am not good at understanding all this % stuffs, thank you =)

Comment: why not `width:100%;` and `height: 100%;` check out the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLthLrj4/2/)

Comment: `min-height:100%; max-height:100%; min-width:100%; max-width:100%;` it seems to not making sense.

Comment: thanks @benjamin but if on different browser viewport, the 100% will scale all my elements in the div proportionally? Or do i have to do something else to my elements to make them scale

Comment: you should not answer questions that can be easily found on google like this. when you do this only more and more of these questions will come to SO and we don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

you have just put height is 100% which means it automatically adjust with your screen

```
@media(max-width:1920px)
{
.yourdivid
{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   float:left;
   height:100%;
   min-height:100%;
   max-height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
}
```